# What is the best way to make sure a jQuery plugin won't ever overwrite a jQuery native method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin, and I was wondering how to make sure that I don't ever overwrite a future jQuery native method.

For example, my plugin is called Foo and usage is `$('selector').foo()`.

jQuery 2.6 has noticed the popularity of Foo and decided that it will include it in the core package. It too is used via `$('selector').foo()`.

I don't want my Foo to overwrite jQuery's native Foo (or else clash).

This is what I came up with...

```
(function($) {

  // If jQuery adds this method, we don't want to overwrite it
  if (typeof $.foo === 'function') {
    return;
  };

  $.fn.foo = function() {
     // Foo
  };  

})(jQuery);
```

Would this be the best way to do it?

Comment: If your implementation of foo is differen't than jQuery's then your plugin would get buggy... This might be a good practice though, maybe i'll try it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can skip the `if` statements and build definition-checking into your function declaration.

```
(function($){

  $.fn.foo = $.fn.foo || function () {
    // only used if $.fn.foo is undefined
  }

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: That is sexy! Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't think anyone can top that. I always forget about exploiting short circuit evaluation and JavaScript returning the first *truthy* operand.

Comment: @alxed - You should note this isn't safe for properties, for example `.length`, `.active` and other things that default to `0` would be overridden here, even when used by jQuery.

Comment: @Nick there are only three non-function properties on the jQuery prototype: `jquery`, `length` and `selector`. As long as you're not naming your plugin any of those three, you should be fine.

Comment: Actually I wasn't going to reinvent the `length` property :P

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better off with:

```
  if ($.foo !== undefined) {
    alert('there is something at foo');
    return;
  };
```

The reason being, your plugin could look like this:

```
$.foo = {
     doSomething: function() { /* do something*/ },
     doSomethingElse: function() { /* do something else*/ }
  };
```

The `typeof` the above is *not* function, but object, so the condition in your example will not behave as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer karim79. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I do `alert($.unwrap);` I get `undefined` even though I am using jQuery 1.4 and `alert($);` gives me the `toString()` of the minified jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do this in a similar way to regular JavaScript programming a `getElementsByClassName` function - you check if it exists and create it if not.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better (performance-wise) version:

```
jQuery.fn.foo || (jQuery.fn.foo = function(){
var $ = jQuery;
(your code goes here)
});
```